# Break HMAC-SHA256 of PAN with known hash?

Tags: hmac

Imagine a database containing hashed (HMAC) Primary Account Numbers (PANs ) and associated identifiable information (e.g. transactions).
Consider a data breach. Prior to the breach, an attacker made specific transactions to make it easy to identify one or more hashed PANs. Could the attacker then work out the SHA256 key and easily brute force all the PANs?

Comment: You are missing some terminology here. SHA256 has no key. HMAC is a keyed hash and can be instantiated with SHA256 and usually written HMAC-SHA256. Actually, you are asking the security of the HMAC, See [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34430/18298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only for a trivial key.**

You have `HMAC(<key>, <secret₁>) = <hash>`. The attacker knows `<hash>` and certain `<secret>`. Having a small search space, different `<secret>` values might be bruteforced.

However, with a proper (long, random) `<key>` the attacker won't be able to recover the other values. The HMAC-SHA256 itself is not reversible, and a long random `<key>` won't let them bruteforce them during their lifetime.

The real risk would be that during the data breach, in addition to the hashed values, the attacker also stole the `<key>`.

Answer (score 1):

This would normally be equivalent to a peppered hash. The attacker should be assumed to know the pepper. It's generally bad practice to assume a salt or pepper will remain secret, and as such, this is not secure practice, since the attack becomes equivalent to normal hash breaking. The information you're hashing doesn't have enough entropy to resist such an attack.

If you consider your pepper (in your case an HMAC key) to be secret, your system is secure only under the assumption that the pepper will *remain* secret after a breach. This, in practice, is impossible. An attacker must be assumed to know the pepper used, and as such should be assumed to be able to break your hashes.

*Normal usage of a salt is to encrypt each user's data with a different, random salt. A pepper is a salt that is the same for every user.*